# Cannot find -lfl when using flex

Tags: gcc, flex-lexer, lex

Here is my sample flex file,

```
%{
/* need this for the call to getlogin() below */
#include <unistd.h>
%}

%%
username        printf("%s\n", getlogin());
%%

main()
{
  yylex();
}
```

I ran the following command,

```
$ flex sample.fl
```

I could see the lex.yy.c file now.

I ran the following gcc command

```
$ gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

and got the following error,

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already have flex installed in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the **flex-static.i686** package in my fedora box solved the issue.

Comment: The package needed seems to be flex-devel now (I'm also using Fedora).